# How can I override an abstract class' property?

Tags: c#, properties, abstract

I have an abstract class named `CharacterBase`. Inside it, I have a few properties. For example:

```
public int Level { get; set; }
```

I have a class named `Character` which inherits from `CharacterBase`. I want to be able to somehow override the `Level` property and make one of my own. For example:

```
int level;

public (override?) int Level
{
    get
    {
        return level;
    }
    set
    {
        level = value;
        Console.WriteLine("The new level is " + level + ".");
    }
}
```

Is it possible to override this property and make one of my own instead of the abstract class's one?

**EDIT:** I marked the `Level` property as virtual. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You can use `new` instead of `override`

Comment: or you can optionally mark it as abstract to force all the inheriting class to implement that property.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer: Making the property abstract in the base class will force children of that class to implement it. Making it virtual, you give the children a choice whether to implement it or not. I both cases, the override keyword is needed in the child class.

Answer (score 5):

To override a property it has to be virtual in base-class and have override in derived class:

```
class CharacterBase {
    public virtual int Level {get;set;}
}

class Character : CharacterBase {
    public override int Level { /* */ }    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want the property to always be implemented by the child class, you could just make it abstract as well:

```
public abstract class CharacterBase
{
    public abstract int Level { get; set; }
}

public class Character : CharacterBase
{
    private int level = 1;
    public override int Level
    {
        get { return level; }
        set 
        {
            level = value;
            Console.WriteLine("The new level is {0}.", level);
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to be able to override it, but not force it to be overridden, you simply change abstract to virtual in the parent class property signature.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to override this property and make one of my own
>   instead of the abstract class's one?

You can use [`new modifier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx) to have your own property instead of inherited, although you can hid base class member with adding new modifier. Note hiding the base class property will takes away the polymorphic behavior from you.

```
public new int Level
{
    get
    {
        return level;
    }
    set
    {
        level = value;
        Console.WriteLine("The new level is " + level + ".");
    }
}
```

[new Modifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

> When used as a declaration modifier, the new keyword explicitly hides
>   a member that is inherited from a base class. When you hide an
>   inherited member, the derived version of the member replaces the base
>   class version. Although you can hide members without using the new
>   modifier, you get a compiler warning. If you use new to explicitly
>   hide a member, it suppresses this warning.

If you want to override the property then use in override as you have in post by make the base class property virtual.

```
class CharacterBase 
{
    public virtual int Level {get;set;}
}

class Character : CharacterBase 
{
    public override int Level { get; set; }    //You can give get set implementation here 
}
```

Comment: You should mention though that if an object is casted to CharacterBase the base Property will be used... That is not good for polymorphism

Comment: I also believe the question was how to override a property, and not how to hide it. This is still a nice addition though.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to override it, it has to be virtual:

```
public abstract class CharacterBase
{
    public virtual int Level { get; set; }
}

public class ConcreteCharacter : CharacterBase
{
    public override int Level
    {
        get
        {
            return 1; //or whatever
        }
        set
        {
            // your implementation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the difference between overriding or using the new operator?

Comment: @GilbertWilliams check the comment under Adils answer

Comment: @GilbertWilliams if you want to be able to use the overridden property even if you access it with a reference of type CharacterBase ... CharacterBase character = new ConcreteCharacter(); ... then it either has to be abstract (then all classes derived from Characterbase have to implement the property) or virtual (only the classes where you want this to change explicitly have to override the property)

Comment: @GilbertWilliams it's therefore a matter if you want this polymorphism. Usually you stick to abstract or virtual to avoid design errors.